# UITextView lineBreakMode not working after setting exclusionPaths

Tags: ios, uitextview

I've a UITextView, contain texts(very long) and a few UIImageView. Every imageView can be move/rotate/resize. All text in this UITextView line-break-mode is `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`
Before insert images, the text line-break-mode works fine.
After insert image/images, move/rotate/resize the imageView, I'll reload the exclusionPath, but this time, the line-break-mode doesn't work. When image closer to left or right side, it'll separate the text character-by-character, not word-to-word.
I've been try lots of methods, still not fixed. I've checked Apple's demo, they have this issue too.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Same Problem here :/ Couldn't find a solution till now.